# LUIS Offline Support

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

1. This might be a basic query but I wanted to confirm if there is any way of using the LUIS services/functionality offline without consuming the online APIs and generating the public key online. By offline, I mean to say if there are any supporting libraries/DLLs available for on-premise solutions by which we can build the Intends/Utterences/Entities and train the NLP system offline.

   (The reason for asking this question is that I want to integrate LUIS with my existing Microsoft Bot application. However, our organization limits the software usage to utilize only on-premise offline software and any online software/services/APIs such as Azure APIs are restricted.)
2. Assuming that there is no such offline support for LUIS AI, are there any other libraries that would provide such support for .NET apps. I have come across Apache OpenNLP but that seems to more of Java-oriented offering.

Any inputs/suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to split your question into two based on your two points. For the second I would ask you to try to describe more in detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LUIS` is based on an online use, like almost all Microsoft Cognitive Services (except Custom vision compact models for example). There is no possibility for offline use, even if it may be useful for some cases like mobile use also.

Moreover (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-resources-faq?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#is-luis-available-on-premises-or-in-private-cloud) in the official documentation):

> Is LUIS available on-premises or in private cloud? => No

For your 2nd question, StackOverflow may not be the right place for this (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and... I don't have a good solution! But would be interested to know one

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. That's what I was looking for in the official docs.

Comment: this comment is no longer accurate

Comment: @ChristianMatthew : if you are talking about the container version of LUIS, it still needs a connection to send the billing to Azure endpoints...

Comment: @ChristianMatthew, can you add more details so that I correct the answer if it is no longer the case?

Comment: @NicolasR I have provided my answer below.  thank you for the push

Answer (score 2):

Luis now has the ability to be fully off-cloud and on-premise through a docker container pull.  This would be available for on-premise and Azure's IoT Edge (intelligent Edge) products.

**Keep in mind**
The described solution still requires a connection for Azure LUIS billing purposes that at the time of this writing is at a 15 minute interval.  I believe this will be adjusted at some point in the future but it is something to keep in mind and plan for.

Link to [Container Support in Azure Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support)

As well, [specifically, LUIS has full integration via this scenario.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto) Where you can install and run LUIS docker containers.  Please, keep in mind at the time of this writing this is ONLY for LUIS. Not QNA, not Bing Spell Check, *not analytics from the LUIS endpoints but there is a container work around for that.

Also, not speech priming or sentiment analysis and a few other features listed in the article.

Lastly, you can look into "Azure Stack" and [IoT Edge here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-edge/)

It's a promising start. There are work arounds you may have to engineer while these services bare out more fruit but keep asking questions and keep raising concerns and more features will surely come!

Comment: Ok, but can you please add a comment on your answer, stating that a "fully off-coud" ability still needs an internet connection and an access to Microsoft endpoint, in order to report billing? That's still a limitation at that time, and as the OP asked in the case here: "our organization limits the software usage to utilize only on-premise offline software and any online software/services/APIs such as Azure APIs are restricted.". So your answer is not compliant with this statement

Comment: you make a good point.  I will update my answer to reflect this point